# How to install GreenAddress Bitcoin Wallet in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, bitcoin

Can someone make a short tutorial about how to install the bitcoin wallet GreenAddress in Ubuntu?

Comment: // , Does a Chrome extension with Chromium count?

Comment: I would rather avoid it.

Comment: // , Well, most of it's written in Javascript. They don't have an Ubuntu package, afaik. Do you have any familiarity with node.js?

Comment: I can't really recommend this wallet or company in general. They've been stringing me along for years with money trapped in the wallet. I'm told now that *maybe* I can have the money back in at least a year. I wrote a post about the UI issues this wallet has: http://mhluska.com/blog/why-you-should-avoid-green-address-bitcoin-wallet

The important thing to know is this is a multisig wallet by default with GreenAddress being the other signer. What this means is that you don't ultimately control your wallet and can get screwed like in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, install Chromium.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Worry not as much with the usual Google big brother worries. It is, for what it's worth, mostly open source. 
Folks really do make a fuss about privacy when Google tries to mess with Chromium too much.

Just make sure to install some privacy protecting extensions like Ghostery or the like, and check those privacy settings!

Anyway, after that's out of the way, visit the Chrome Web Store for apps at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps.

They have apps and apps.

Search ye in the apps for GreenAddress, brave adventurer!

[image]

Click ye this link, e'n braver adventurer!

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/greenaddress

Click the blue "Add to Chrome" button with the plus next to the green GreenAddress result, and follow through the usual Chrome Web Store extension installation prompts.

Now, try clicking the Ubuntu button in the upper left corner.

A wilde GreenAddress appeared!

Click that GreenAddress!

[image]

I would, if I may, offer a side not from bitter personal experience:

MAKE SURE TO TAKE THOSE MNEMONICS AND WRITE THEM DOWN *AND* PRINT THEM OUT *AND* COPY THEM TO A USB TO SAVE SECURELY. This is real money. If you know how to use GPG, encrypt one of the mnemonics to a trusted friend, or print one out and put it in an envelope to give to your Mom. Besides, it makes a great conversation starter. "So, my boy, what's in the envelope?" "Well, this guy on the internet told me to send you a letter..."